# Force applied on a massless pulley

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity

Hi guys I had a question regarding this diagram. 
[image: enter link description here]

My teacher told me that $$F-2T = 0$$  Hence,$$F=2T$$ but I am confused that shouldn't it be:-$$F+2T=0$$ and hence, $$F=-2T$$
(Considering pulley to be massless)?

Comment: That is not at all a good doubt! You have made the fbd for the pulley wrong and the teacher is right here!!!

Comment: @Aditya Garg can you please explain I am new to NLM

Comment: Do you really think that the strings are pushing up on the pulley?  Tension is bi-directional; it is pulling up on the masses, and pulling down on the pulley.

Answer (score 2):

The FBD for the pulley is shown below and if $\hat u$ is the unit vector in the upward direction then  $F\hat u + 2T(-\hat u) =0 \Rightarrow F=2T$.

[image]

Comment: thanks but can you please explain why my FBD was wrong . Because many other FBD's where the pulley is stationary we draw 2T as I drew

Comment: @user198885  All I can suggest is that the upper string has been labelled "twice" and that there is actually only one force there.. A force $F$ or a force $2T$ so it might have been better to have one arrow with the label $F=2T$.

Answer (score 0):

Your force diagram is unclear. The arrows of the tensions at least are unclear. Because, which of the objects are we looking at?

- **On the boxes**, sure, there is a tension $T$ force pulling upwards (and also a weight $w$ pulling downwards). And the tension is obviously pulling upwards, since it is the force that holds the box up and prevents it from falling.
- **On the pulley** on the other hand, the tensions forces from the boxes are directed **downwards**. Because, the boxes pull down in the pulley (without the boxes, the pulley would be carrying no load (other than it's own weight)).

You can compare it with yourself lifting something off of the ground. The thing you lift is feeling an upwards force. This is why is gets lifted. But you yourself feel a downwards force, which is why it is tough to lift. This is **Newton's 3rd law**; the fact that forces always come in pairs. If one box feels an upwards force, it is because something else feels the same force, but opposite.

- So, the pulley feels two **downwards**-pulling tension forces; one from each string. Furthermore, the pulley also feels an upwards force from the upper string. Clearly, this one is pointed upwards, because this string holds the pulley from falling.

But how do you know that this upwards force is $2T$? It is not obvious. You can only know that by using Newton's 1st law on the pulley:

$$\sum F=0 \quad\Leftrightarrow \quad \text{upwards force}-T-T=0\quad\Leftrightarrow \quad \text{upwards force}=T+T=2T$$

The two $T$s here are the two downwards tensions from the boxes (downwards, so we add a negative sign).

Okay, now we know that the upwards force from the pulley is $2T$ along the upper strong. We also know that a force $F$ pulls at the top of this string.

- If we imagine looking at the very top particle of this string, then that particle is being pulled **downwards** by the force of $2T$, of the same reason as before: The $2T$ that pull upwards on the pulley, pull **downwards** in the particle that holds the pulley. This top particle is being pulled in downwards by the pulley with that force.

Although this top particle is being pulled in downwards with $2T$, it doesn't fall. Because the force $F$ holds on to it upwards. We can do Newton's 1st law again, this time on this top particle:

$$\sum F=0 \quad\Leftrightarrow \quad \text{upwards force}-\text{upwards force}=0\quad\Leftrightarrow \quad F-2T=0$$

And there you have it. $F=2T$. I believe the confused started because you weren't clear on what object you were looking at - on what object your force diagram was drawn for. Defining you "system" is a very important step to avoid mixing up directions.

Comment: Thanks a ton @Steeven